# changing format of RichTextBox without selecting any text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, text

I would like to create a Richtextbox which load a huge file (several pages of text in some format) and based on format it formats the text (let's say it display html).

I found how to change format of text using selection, but that is very slow and resource expensive. Is there a way to append a preformatted text to Rich Text Box? So that I can format each element and then append it.

Comment: What platform are you using WinForms, WPF, Web?

Comment: That only tells how to hide that from user, but it doesn't explain how to change format in a better manner than selecting it's parts and changing format, keep in mind there could be millions of selections needed to display complicated page, a simple document you display in word within few seconds, could take few days to load using this way

Comment: Why not save your formatted document in rtf format, then use RichTextBox1.LoadFile(pathToYourRTF)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you if not the answer you are looking for

But [RichTextBox.CanPaste Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.canpaste.aspx) determines whether you can paste information from the Clipboard in the **specified data format**. Please see link the for the [System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dataformats) it will support